# Proper way to refer to references in natbib?

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I'm using the `natbib`package for managing my references in my latex document.

Is it correct to refer to a reference in the following way:

```
A survey can be found in Ref.~\citep{Radke:2005ug}
```

Which is typeset as: A survey can be found in Ref. (Radke et al, 2005)

Since my bibliography is not numbered I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do it. Or should I avoid the passive voice altogether?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! You could try `A survey can be found in~\citet{Radke:2005ug}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you reference is typically governed by whatever journal, book och other publication series you intend to publish in. The "Ref." seems unnecessary to me and in this case I would have written the line "A survey can be found in Radke et al. (2005)

```
A survey can be found in \citet {Radke:2005ug}
```

But again, the way this is done varies. The natbib package provides numerous ways to "bend" the referencing so check the standard you are supposed to follow and the `natbib` documentation fo the way to do it.

Your first suggestion is often called passive referencing whereas my sugestion is referred to as active. Both are used but obviously in different situations.

Comment: I agree, a common guideline is this: `\cite` and `\citep` should be used like footnotes grammatically and `\citet` can be used as part of a sentence.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn’t aware of the passive/active referencing. However, giving it a second thought I think it should be avoided. It probably reads better something like ``A survey by Radke et al.(2005)…``